# Should we create a collaboration sandbox?

Tags: discussion, resource

**Background**

Sandboxes are a tool that allows edit activity without overwhelming the main page with bumped posts.  They can be set up in various ways for different purposes.

The gist  of the implementation is a dummy question (containing instructions), as a placeholder, with a number of dummy answer placeholders.  It can be created in either the main site or the meta site.  The editing is done in the answers, then the answer is released back for someone else to use when it's no longer needed.  Any editing in any of the answers causes, at most, just the sandbox question to be bumped on the main page (and even that can be suppressed if desired).

Sites use them in different ways for activities that generate a lot of edits.  For example:

- figuring out complicated post formatting issues
- drafting a long post
- getting feedback or editing help on a post before submitting it

**Why do it on Arts & Crafts?**

The main application I envision on our site is an "off-label" use, where edit bumping might be a consideration, but isn't the primary concern.  It would serve as a collaboration tool.  Stack Exchange doesn't really have a provision for collaborating, where multiple users jointly prepare a post before releasing it for general viewing.  There are a couple of workarounds that could serve high-rep users, but nothing that all users could take advantage of.  A sandbox would afford an essentially private workspace, with the side benefit of not bumping the main page.

We occasionally have applications like these:

- Roll out a site event or feature (like the Community Gallery).  These things have a lot of considerations, and the planners would want to get it right before announcing it.
- Collaborative effort on site resources (some ideas are percolating behind the scenes).
- Joint effort on a question or answer (I have a potential current example), or both, as a collaborative self-answered question.
- User wrestling with a post that requires significant rewrite.  Or a new user whose post needs a lot of help from an experienced user may just find it more palatable to do it in private.

**Caveats?**

Sandboxes often don't get a lot of regular use.  They're a resource for the occassions when they're helpful.  There are some non-obvious considerations, though, and they do require some maintenance to keep them clean and ready to use (although nothing if it doesn't get used).  [How can we make a Sandbox happen?](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3106) was posted on the Interpersonal Skills Meta site some years ago, and includes an informative answer by Monica Cellio about things learned when implementing it on the Worldbuilding site.

**What are people's thoughts?**

- Yes, let's do it.  I might even use it.
- I don't envision ever using it, and don't care either way.
- Avoid doing it, like the plague.
- Something else?

Comment: [Example Sandbox](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7183/sandbox-for-proposed-questions) on Worldbuilding.

Comment: Worldbuilding did quite a job on theirs.  They use it for a different purpose, and it apparently gets a workout. If we do one here, I expect it would be a bit different.

Comment: Can you expand on that? Do you have a better idea for what the format would look like here?

Comment: @Joachim, I just got introduced to sandboxes today (I asked on MSE about provisions to support collaboration and that was suggested in an answer). I was envisioning a tool for private collaboration.  It looks like Worldbuilding is using it more to encourage stuff in a public workspace. A site can have more than one for different purposes. Beyond thinking that a private collaboration space would be a lot simpler than theirs, I assumed figuring that out would be the next step (maybe do it in a sandbox, and then create the sandbox we did it in).

Comment: But you're thinking about a private collaboration space? How could that work?

Comment: @Joachim, the gist would be that it would probably be on Meta (low traffic), and configured so any edits wouldn't bump it.  So there would be no indication anywhere that there was activity.  The only way someone would stumble on work in progress would be if they were using the sandbox (low odds of concurrent use), or they were a busybody and just happened to randomly check it to see if anything was there. Here's the MSE Q: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/377864/is-there-a-way-for-users-to-collaborate-on-a-post. The sandbox Q would get buried by other posts.

Answer (score 1):

### Yes, let's do it. I <strike>might</strike> *will* even use it.

Admittedly, it was only until I saw an example that I really got the concept, but yes, this sounds like a great idea to be more welcoming to new users, and get a good feeling for what topics users are interested in. Additionally, it will improve activity.

I vote for having such a thread on Meta: on the main page it might be too confusing for some. But definitely a [featured](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/featured) thread.